# A question of etiquette

Tags: discussion

On the main Stack Exchange SP site, if you ask a question that after research and feedback develops in a new direction (still the same problem, but no longer exactly matches the title), is it better to post a new up-to-date question, or just keep tacking updates on to the original one?

My main concern is readability, people are more willing to help if they can read/understand your question quickly. Tacking on update after update makes the question intimidatingly long, in my opinion.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would say to edit it if it still similar. Problem is someone could already have answered the old question in an effort to gain lazy rep, and in this case they won't edit. You should take your decision based on readability and how much the question will change (ninja question aren't see to well). Have you a specific case in mind?

Comment: I posted this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/57332/11647 but I'm now thinking the answer to my problem is to use custom event receivers and not the method listed in the title. Wasn't sure if it was okay to edit the main question significantly to keep it concise, or if I should make a whole new one, or just keep adding on to the original until I get a complete solution. I see how the "ninja question" is frowned upon, and that's one thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: About that question, I would have continued posting details like you did. The answers seem not helping - so I wouldn't see that as "ninja". Thats is just my opinion. Anyway, since you seem to have found the solution, I would leave it in a self answer to avoid other people "spending time without reason" (not meaning the question is bad- i mean avoid others beliving it still needs an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @SPArchaeologist (if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it)

> About that question, I would have continued posting details like you did. The answers seem not helping - so I wouldn't see that as "ninja". Thats is just my opinion. Anyway, since you seem to have found the solution, I would leave it in a self answer to avoid other people "spending time without reason" (not meaning the question is bad- i mean avoid others beliving it still needs an answer)

Comment: nono, don't worry ^_^' I had not posted an answer only because I hoped some mod would give a more general hint/answer (yes, I am speaking about you, @KitMenke :P). But SharePoint meta is a low traffic area, so fell free to reuse my comment as an answer if you like ^_^

Comment: Hooray for nice people! (: